# OS X Python: alias not working anymore, where to link to?

Tags: python, bash, path

I had brew doctor complaining, that I had a version of python in use/local/bin and that this could cause problems. So It proposed to get rid of it. Which I did. Now my scripts don't work from Terminal because it is looking for it and is now complaining `-bash: /usr/local/bin/pythonw: No such file or directory`
. Clever me went to System Library and copied the missing alias' into /usr/local/bin/. Then I got `pythonw: posix_spawn: /usr/local/bin/pythonw2.7: Exec format error` when starting the script.

I have tried to change bash_profile and it contains:

```
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rabbitmq_server-3.6.6/sbin
##
# Your previous /Users/macbook/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/macbook/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2017-02-20_at_14:02:39
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2017-02-20_at_14:02:39: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
source ~/ .profile
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

as I was led to install rvm, MacPorts and RabbitMQ.

When I run `file /usr/local/bin/python` I get:

```
 /usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/bin/python (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/usr/local/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Does this mean, I need a symlink?

**EDIT:** I used time machine magic to set back the python files in /usr/local/bin. running my script from Desktop now throws me:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/env python: No such file or directory
```

After time machine I noticed, that the alias' were now 'whited out' and when I double-click them, I get told 'original could not be found' - now I am really confused… this was the set-up, that worked before .

So before I dig myself in any deeper, can someone please guide me out of this? How do I get back to the 'proper set-up'? And please, don't expect too much knowledge of me. Big Thank you!

Comment: While many users is happy with `brew`, it is well known that it notoriously giving bad advices. In the beginning it suggesting delete the whole `/usr/local` prior brew installation. Many users lost their `mysql` data. Looks like, the `doctor` is similar. You screwed up an working system based on wrong advices.

Comment: seems like you're right! But how to fix this?

Comment: Well, I fear a complete system restore will most likely be your best option if your own knowledge is slim as is mine. I am not sure how you _got rid of_ python, but it apparently also got your pythonw removed, which is a different executable. Also, you mention something about using MacPorts. I've read on a lot of forums that using Macports & Homebrew together is always dis-adviced. Regarding python; there is a python version installed by macOS which is a build of python2.7 if I am correct. If you want to install another version always use the python.org packages _or_ Homebrew _or_ MacPorts.

Comment: well, I still have all the files in usr/bin/library so is there no way to re-link the alias'? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did have to make a system restore. What I learned and what should be stated everywhere: Using all the different installation options (pip, homebrew, MacPorts) as one is being led to far too easily can corrupt paths and I came across about a lot of similar issues form other users mixing installation methods. As I am no expert (who'd have guessed...) I can't give any further advice on this. I lost two days for saving files, system restore and reinstallation of missing packages.